# How to read data from file System and send complete message to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, fs

In my implementation, if a user searches from a client, I want to check if the string is part of the file. I am sending that line data back to the client as a response.

My issue is lets assume that a user wants to search for `testid012`. So with my current code, it only finds a singular line that contains the search string. Instead I want to send a response with multiple lines that include the search string, which in this case is `testid012`. Is this doable?

searchService.js

```
fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
            lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                    results.push({
                    filename:logfile.filename,
                    value:line
                    });
                }
            });
            // when you are done reading the file
            done();
        });
```

dit/server.log

```
testid012 Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industrytestid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing and typesetting industrytestid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry
Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry,testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry

testid013 Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing and typesetting industry,testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industrytestid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry
Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry
```

Comment: its do-able, but I highly recommend not doing it this way, I suggest you index your file inside Solr, and query Solr for such search terms, or, at least if you don't have Solr, use it in any database you have which is also I don't recommend but at least not a file search the way you are doing it.

Comment: I can not use database for this requirement,  i have do go with file search. Any good example how can i achieve that using FS.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will work, but the reason you are only getting one line is your are splitting your input by line end.  Seems like you need to figure out how your events are separated and change your `data.split()` call.

If there is data that starts every event like `[EVENT] This is an event` then use a regex to split on that.
`data.split('[EVENT] ')`

Comment: we are rendering events from Kafka bus as a string each event  then writing it to file system.